# smarty access variable with string of variable name

Tags: php, smarty, smarty2

I am not sure if this is possible but I have a variable assigned in a file I cannot change.

`$smarty->assign('signature',$account->options[SIGNATURE]);`

It is just set to 1 or 0 but I need that value later in the file I am working in. From a settings page I have an array that will validate a signature field based on this value. This is inside of a foreach loop and I was hoping I could do something like `{if ${$settings.signature} eq 1}` where `{$settings.signature}` would evaluate to signature.

In php it is basically variable variables I believe. How can I do this in smarty?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a $:

```
{$settings.$signature}
```

will return $settings[0] if $signature is 0

If instead what you need is the value of $settings0:

```
{$settings{$signature}}
```

read the [Smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl) for more info about variables

Comment: Sorry my question is kinda confusing. $settings.signature will evaluate to the string 'signature' so this can be done for multiple settings of different names. I can build the array with these names to access each one

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you write a simple example of the contents of $settings?

Comment: $settings[] = array('category'=>'General', 'roles'=>array(STANDARD),'type'=>'bool','label'=>'Signature Pad', 'signature'=>'signature');

Comment: so... maybe you want... {$value=$settings.signature} and then {$settings.$value} ? if not, how would you do whatever you are asking in pure php and then maybe whe can translate it to smarty?

Comment: If you have used PHP variable variables it is like this 

$Hello = "World"; $a = "Hello";  $a; //Returns Hello  $$a; //Returns World

Comment: Then as the second example: {${$a}}

Comment: I do not think you can have braces inside of braces in smarty

Comment: ummm I just noticed you tagged the question as smarty2. I suppose  that was introduced in smarty3.

Comment: In that case we should hopefully be making that update soon. thanks for the help